# Reset Input of form-group

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I got a modal window that holds a form-group that I use to create new activities for an activity overview. But if the user press "close" in my modal window rather than "Add Activity", the activity disappears. This is great. But I'd like to also reset the fields that I got so they don't sit on what the user put in last they used it.

I found that you could use something like the below to achieve this:

```
function OnCreateNewActivityBtnClick() {
    $('#new-activity-modal').find('form-group').each(function(){
        $(this).find('input-group').reset();
    });
}
```

But that does nothing. I am using bootstrap and the HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="new-activity-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1>Add New Activity</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="tab-navigation">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active">
                            <a href="#new-activity-modal-activity-abstract-tab" aria-controls="new-activity-modal-activity-abstract-tab"
                               role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Activity Abstract</a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="presentation">
                            <a href="#new-activity-modal-activity-description-tab" aria-controls="new-activity-modal-activity-description-tab"
                               role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Activity Description</a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="presentation">
                            <a href="#help-tab" aria-controls="help-tab"
                               role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Finalize</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="new-activity-modal-activity-abstract-tab">
                        <div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                        <span id="add-addon-styling" class="input-group-addon">Status</span>
                                        <!-- TODO: Make this automatically rather than hardcode -->
                                        <select class="form-control" id="new-activity-modal-status-dropdown">
                                            <option value="NA">N/A</option>
                                            <option value="ON_TRACK">On Track</option>
                                            <option value="DONE">Done</option>
                                            <option value="ISSUE">Issue</option>
                                            <option value="BEHIND">Behind</option>
                                            <option value="ABANDONED">Abandoned</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <span class="input-group-addon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="The Status of the Activity. Usually On Track but otherwise set to N/A if unsure.">
                                            <b>?</b>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-group" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                        <span id="add-addon-styling" class="input-group-addon">Activity Name</span>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="new-activity-modal-name-field"
                                               aria-describedby="new-activity-modal-name-field" required>
                                        <span class="input-group-addon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                                              title="The Name of the Activity. This name appears in the Activity Overview.">
                                            <b>?</b>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-group" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                        <span id="add-addon-styling" class="input-group-addon">Responsible</span>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="new-activity-modal-name-field"
                                               aria-describedby="new-activity-modal-responsible-field">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                                              title="The responsible person for this activity. This it the go-to person for questions, progress and reports.">
                                            <b>?</b>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span id="add-addon-styling" class="input-group-addon">Department</span>
                                        <select class="form-control" id="new-activity-modal-department-dropdown">
                                            <option value="culture">Culture</option>
                                            <option value="commercial">Commercial</option>
                                            <option value="economy">Economy</option>
                                            <option value="technical-department">Technical Department</option>
                                            <option value="it">IT</option>
                                            <option value="flight-department">Flight Department</option>
                                            <option value="legal">Legal</option>
                                            <option value="ground-operation">Ground Operation</option>
                                            <option value="bdo">BDO</option>
                                            <option value="administration">Administration</option>
                                            <option value="training">Training</option>
                                            <option value="passenger-service">Passenger Service</option>
                                            <option value="cabin">Cabin</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <span class="input-group-addon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                                              title="The department this activity belongs to.">
                                            <b>?</b>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group date" id="new-activity-modal-datetimepicker-start" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                    <span id="add-addon-styling" class="input-group-addon">Start Time</span>
                                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                                          title="The start of the activity. Usually today's date.">
                                        <b>?</b>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group date" id="new-activity-modal-datetimepicker-end">
                                    <span id="add-addon-styling" class="input-group-addon">End Time</span>
                                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
                                          title="The estimated end of the activity.">
                                        <b>?</b>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="new-activity-modal-activity-description-tab">
                        <div class="row">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-bg" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="OnModalCreateNewActivityBtnClick()">Add Activity</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-bg" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="OnCloseNewActivityBtnClick()">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why don't you wrap your elements inside the `form` and reset the `form` itself. However, to post the data to save in DB, you need a `form`. A **[Tutorial](http://www.formget.com/jquery-reset-form/)** and a **[DEMO](http://www.aorank.com/tutorial/reset_jquery/resetjquery.html)**.

Comment: I'm using bootstrap so I thought I could just use what they provided.

Comment: They just provide it for sample.. You need to have everything which is going backend, inside a `form` which is a good practice.. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
function OnCreateNewActivityBtnClick() {
    $('#new-activity-modal').find('.form-group').each(function(){
        $(this).find('.input-group').reset();
    });
}
```

You need to use `.` to use class as a selector.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem. It still doesn't reset any of the fields.

Comment: is it in the form element?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function OnCreateNewActivityBtnClick() {
  $('#new-activity-modal').find('form-group').each(function(){
     obj = $(this).find('.input-group');
     obj.val(obj.data('defaultValue'));
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried your edited version too but nothing happens. The fields don't change.

Comment: i mean the answer given by @void